# Ruby Rails update all atrribute using param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently im using this code to update one attribute, is there any way i can update all 'title' at once ? like using `update_all` maybe ?

```
title= params['myform']['title']
@book.update_attribute(:title, title)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean update all titles?  all titles of every book ?  that is what `update_all` does.  which version of rails?

Comment: you want to update all the titles of the books to same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a way:

```
ModelName.update_all(:title => title)
```

More details [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).